# Getting all possible down- and right edge paths in a n x n grid

Tags: java, algorithm

**Problem 15:**
Starting in the top left corner of a 2×2 grid, there are 6 routes (without backtracking) to the bottom right corner.
How many routes are there through a 20×20 grid?

[image]

So my attempt at [Problem 15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15) is kinda bruteforcy because I try to get permutations of all of the possible valid paths by going from right to left and changing the predecessor of the first change of direction. For example, when I have a 2x2 grid (look at the Problem 15 link graphics) the first path I'll take is **right - right - down - down** and the last one I'll take is **down - down - right - right**, which is also my termination criteria. I add the possible valid paths into a list and also use that list to determine whether the valid path has been already added or not. And to permutate a path I'll do what I've mentioned earlier: I go from right to left in my array (Which in the graphic would be the bottom right corner where the arrowhead points at) and change the first element of which the next element is different from itself. So **right - right - down - down** would become **right - right - right - down**, which is obviously invalid since you have to have the same amount of rights and downs to be able to reach the end corner. So what I thought is to make another loop going from left to right and change as many elements as needed to get a valid path. So in this example **right - right - right - down** becomes **down - right - right - down**.

Also, what I forgot is that I'm not counting the points, I'm counting the edges from top left corner to bottom right corner.

So I have already written some code, but it doesn't work at all.

```
package projecteuler;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Projecteuler {
    public static final int GRIDSIZE = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<boolean[]> paths = new ArrayList<>();

        paths.add(new boolean[GRIDSIZE * 2]);
        for(int i = 0; i < GRIDSIZE; i++) {
            paths.get(0)[i] = true;
            paths.get(0)[GRIDSIZE * 2 - 1 - i] = false;
        }

        boolean[] buf = paths.get(0).clone();
        printArr(buf);
        boolean tmp;
        while(!checkTerminate(paths)) {
            while(paths.contains(buf)) {
                tmp = buf[buf.length - 1];
                for(int i = buf.length - 1; buf[i - 1] != tmp && 0 < i; i--) {
                    buf[i] = !buf[i];
                    for(int j = 0; checkValid(buf) && j < i; j++)
                        buf[j] = !buf[j];
                }
            }
            paths.add(buf.clone());
            printArr(buf);
        }
        System.out.println(paths.size());
    }

    public static boolean checkTerminate(ArrayList<boolean[]> paths) {
        boolean[] endPath = new boolean[GRIDSIZE * 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < GRIDSIZE; i++) {
            endPath[i] = false;
            endPath[GRIDSIZE * 2 - 1 - i] = true;
        }
        return paths.contains(endPath);
    }

    public static boolean checkValid(boolean[] arr) {
        int countR = 0,
            countL = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
            if(arr[i])
                countR++;
            else
                countL++;

        return countR == countL;
    }

    public static void printArr(boolean[] arr) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i] ? "right " : "down ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It somehow doesn't change anything anywhere.

```
right right down down 
right right down down 
right right down down 
right right down down ...
```

and so on is all it's outputting. It seems that the code simply doesn't permutate my path, but also doesn't get stuck in any of the for loops. My best guess would be that my function criteria are placed in the wrong sequence

I also thought of a solution with backtracking like we did for a labyrinth two years ago in school, but I want to see if this approach is anywhere viable or not before redoing everything.

**EDIT:**
I'll try to implement the images of the 2 x 2 grid example asap, but the ProjectEuler website is under maintainance at the moment.

Comment: Finally, a programming challenge question showing actual effort to solve the problem before posting...

Comment: The question is **very poorly** written. Although you've made the necessary efforts before posting a question on Stack Overflow, the title of the post and the way you've described the problem is absurd: you shouldn't be assuming that people already know the question you're talking about. And external links to the real question are just unacceptable. Edit the post and include all necessary detail in the description right here, and also modify the title to something that actually breifly describes the real question.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks for noticing my efforts, but somehow people are still downvoting my post. Maybe my approach is way too dumb to even be taken seriously haha

Comment: @progyammer thanks for you comment I'll do that in a wim

Comment: @LordScrat No one will ever downvote your post because of a "poor approach". We're all here to help each other learn.

Comment: Do note that the question only asks you to *count* the routes, not actually build each and every one of them. Counting them is significantly easier.

Comment: @harold hmm yea, but the way I try it should simply have all valid paths in it without duplicates... if only it'd work haha. But what do you mean with counting is much easier? I still have to somehow get the possible paths and check if they are valid and everything, or am I having a brainfart?

Comment: @LordScrat there are various solutions to count them with generating any paths (eg DP or purely with combinatorial math). Even if you do want to generate them, consider that a valid path is a permutation of W steps "right" and H steps "down", so you could generate them based on that (or do the math based on that)

Comment: You should really have made it clear what a "2x2" grid means - I misunderstood it and thought there were only two routes (because I mistook it for a "1x1" grid in your terms)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I added images from the Problem site itself, those should be enough for that matter I hope

Comment: Do you know what binomial coefficient is?

Comment: @DAle funny that you mentioned those, those are one of the few things we couldn't get through this year in Math (We're gonna start off with it in September when class starts again). So to answer your question: nope sorry. But I know a bit about them cause I used it for pascal triangle (dunno how it is called in english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is given by the number of combinations of "down" and "right" movements we can have. Since there is no backtracking, there are `N` downwards and `N` rightwards movements in total (in any route, for an `NxN` grid). There are `2N` movements in total.

We can obtain this using the *binomial coefficient*, <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> (pronounced "n choose r"), which is the number of ways of choosing `r` objects from `n` objects (each of which can be two things). In our case an "object" is either a downward or rightward movement. This is given by

[image]

Thus the number we want is:

[image]

For `N = 2` this gives `6`. For `N = 20` this gives `137846528820`.

Answer (score 2):

Let a step in right be termed as R and a step down is termed as D.

> In order to reach from top-left to bottom-right on a n rows and m column grid, you will have to go right m times and go down n times.

Essentially, ***you will have to get all the possible arrangements of m R's and n D's.***

---

Example: For a 2 by 2 grid, the number of unique permutations of the word RRDD will be the number of ways in which you can go, viz.

- RRDD
- RDRD
- DRDR
- DDRR

---

Google the formula to calculate the permutations of letters with repetition, which is given by:

> n! / ( r<sub>1</sub>! * r<sub>2</sub>! ... ), where sum of all r's is n.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1424380/286229) on Math SE pops up first when looking for repetitive letter permutation count, and the [second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1424406/286229) explains better in my opinion.

---

So, to return the count AND even to return the paths, you don't need to traverse the maze at all. Just do the formula calculation for first one and print the permutations for second problem.

Giving the paths when certain steps are off grid will be the only case that requires you to actually traverse the maze.

---

**UPDATE:**

It helps to visualize the formula for permutation of repeated letters.

Here is a slide that demonstrates that case. See how the 2 E's end up duplicating the arrangements when generating the permutations. In general, any letter that's repeated *r* times will cause *r*! duplication because wherever in the arrangement that letter is put, it can be replaced with another same letter without giving a new permutation.

That way, if we divide the total *n*! permutations with *r*!, we get the actual unique permutations.

[image: Repeated letter permutations]

<sub>*[Image Source](http://slideplayer.com/slide/9323322/28/images/3/Permutations+with+Repetition.jpg)*</sub>